# Exporting and save in folder RadHtmlChart to PDF - RadHtmlChart - UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, radhtmlchart

I'm using RadHtmlChart and I want to save the chart to `App_data/Export/`  But it is not working. It exports to PDF, but it's not able to save to a local folder.

```
var relativePath = "~/App_Data/Export/";

RadClientExportManager1.PdfSettings.ProxyURL = ResolveUrl(relativePath);
RadClientExportManager1.PdfSettings.FileName = "test123.pdf";
```

Comment: show the code to save the file.I don't think assigning filename will save the file.if you are getting any error pls share that too

Comment: Check that export folder's Security Settings